# Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent in Wicket

Tags: wicket, presentation

I am getting the "Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent" issue in Wicket.I see that the html files are present in the package where class files are present in both application installation location of glassfish server and the WAR file.

Comment: This problem description is not sufficient for us to help you.  We need to see some code.

Comment: The question possibly duplicates Java/Wicket: Compile Basic Hello World with Resources . Check if you're using maven and if you don't miss filtering of source files to include the markup.

Comment: where is the location of your web pages?. Last time i got this error. it was cause Wicket couldn't find the corresponding web pages so i put them in the same location as their class files

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you include the *filtering* settings in our `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
...
</build>
```

You can check the generated `pom.xml` after creating a quickstart project following https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for Maven users.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Gradle, include the following in your `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs += ['src/main/java']
            includes = ["**"]
            // or specifically: includes = ["**/*.html"]
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that the HTML files will be added to the WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

- the HTML file is misnamed
- the resolving component fails to find the corresponding HTML file to the Wicket java class
- the HTML files are not included in the WAR